# Rainbow kit only showing qr code even the metamask extension is installed

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend, blockchain

I have installed rainbow kit in my react app. I am having an issue that when I connect to metamask, it shows qr code and an option to install the metamask even I have already installed the metamask. It should open the connect wallet popup. The same code was working in my previous projects. Here is my rainbow kit configuration.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import Head from "./components/layout/head";
import Headline from "./components/layout/headline";
import { StateContextProvider } from "./context";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import '@rainbow-me/rainbowkit/styles.css';
import { darkTheme } from "@rainbow-me/rainbowkit";
import {
  getDefaultWallets,
  RainbowKitProvider,
} from '@rainbow-me/rainbowkit';
import { configureChains, createConfig, WagmiConfig } from 'wagmi';
import {
  mainnet,
  polygon,
  optimism,
  arbitrum,
  zora,
  bscTestnet,
} from 'wagmi/chains';
import { alchemyProvider } from 'wagmi/providers/alchemy';
import { publicProvider } from 'wagmi/providers/public';
import Slidebar from "./components/slidebar/Slidebar";
import Endline from "./components/endline/endline";




const { chains, publicClient } = configureChains(
  [mainnet, polygon, optimism, arbitrum, zora],
  [
    alchemyProvider({ apiKey: 'y5GcR0NBerm6Zg38XyTQxyO9FMw_TY4I' }),
    publicProvider()
  ]
);

const { connectors } = getDefaultWallets({
  appName: 'magicbag',
  projectId: 'f12c6b58850adba8695a7dd824637355',
  chains
});

const wagmiConfig = createConfig({
  autoConnect: true,
  connectors,
  publicClient
})
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));







root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <WagmiConfig config={wagmiConfig} >
      <RainbowKitProvider coolMode modalSize="compact" chains={chains} theme={darkTheme()}  >
        <StateContextProvider>
          <Head />
          <Headline />
          <div className="flex justify-between items-center px-0 sm:px-10  mx-auto max-w-[1440px] h-[calc(100vh - 215px)] ">

            <Slidebar />
            <App />
          </div>
          <div className="  mx-auto max-w-[1440px]" >
            <Endline /></div>
        </StateContextProvider>
      </RainbowKitProvider>
    </WagmiConfig>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint.
reportWebVitals();
```

Here is my package.json

```js
{
  "name": "magicbag",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@material-tailwind/react": "^2.0.6",
    "@rainbow-me/rainbowkit": "^1.0.11",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bignumber.js": "^4.0.4",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "ethers": "^5.7.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-fast-marquee": "^1.6.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-spinners": "^0.13.8",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.3",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.5",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "viem": "^1.10.14",
    "wagmi": "^1.4.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "web3": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if you have Metamask installed in your browser but have temporarily switched it off. It just happened to me. I had turned it off because it was inserting some nonsense into my console while developing something that doesn't require a wallet, and I didn't want to see it while troubleshooting.

Later, a couple of sites, including my client's, suddenly started asking me to scan a QR when I tried to add my wallet via the RainbowKit dialog.
Once I switched it back on, those sites started interacting with the browser plugin again.

In Chrome, click the extensions icon and choose "Manage Extensions" and see if it is switched on or off with the toggle on the bottom right of its card. [image: Metamask extension]

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks